# How to find the channel of a video without using ffmpeg

Tags: android

Can we determine whether the audio in a video is mono or stereo(without using ffmpeg)? I am unable to found any method in MediaMetadataRetreiver.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use MediaPlayer() and try to open a media file. Once open you can easily find info for both audio and video track using getTrackType() and getFormat().
Specifically for audio track you can get number of channels from MediaFormat using key KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT.